# Pentaho report designer: display a bar chart

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

Here is the problem:

I want to show in a chart, using Pentaho report designer, the number of tickets by the resolution duration calculated earlier in the DB.

I have joined an image of the wanted report.

[image: report image]

I've tried the following:

In the chart I've set priority in the category-column, and the count (of tickets) in the value-columns, and in series by value: `duration < 1, duration < 2 or > 1 , ....` It didn't work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Check this out: http://www.joyofdata.de/blog/the-making-of-a-pretty-web-stats-report-with-pentaho-report-designer/ - you are not just going to learn how to make a bar chart - but also how to make a line and a pie chart and a table! wow :)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're trying to put basic charting to your report. May I offer you 2 links for you to follow? It's been helpful to me in my early days.

1. [A Comprehensive Report Design Tutorial](http://www.pentahoevalcenter.com/content-creation-delivery/comprehensive-report-design-tutorial/)
2. http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/Reporting/04.+Designing+a+report